# Home directory for Active Directory authenticated users based on parsed username

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, sssd

I have an NFS share with user home directories mounted on a web server. I want to enable UserDir in apache, but the home directories are not a straight-forward "/home/username" path. Instead, they're organized into a hierarchy based on their username. For example, a username may be ab1234 (always two letters followed by four numbers). The hierarchy for that home folder would be /ab/ab12/ab1234.

In the sssd.conf I know that there are basic parameters for parsing the username out of the username@domain string, but is there anything that can parse that username further into parts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a workaround that doesn't involve the "UserDir" directive. I've used a mod-rewrite rule to in the VirtualHost directive parse the URL after the server name path and rewrite the URL accordingly:

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) /$1/$1$2/$1$2$3/www [L,PT]
```